# How to allow users to enter custom amount vs charging set amount in stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Thus far, I've only seen examples/tutorials for stripe in which you declare an amount via choosen library to charge customers/clients. How would you write code that allows the user to input custom amount for say  a "pay bill" or "donation" form.  Conceptually it seems this might be an if/else statement that sets a high/low parameter but I'm not entirely sure nor how to code this to work with Stripe API. Could really use some help here. Ultimate goal is to make a simple payment page that allows user to make a custom payment and then create a customer object to charge customer at a later date.

Answer (score 4):

(I realize this is an older question, but I figure the information might be useful to some people.)

Here's a [simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ufa8xr/) of a Checkout [custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) where the user can specify the amount.

Of course, Checkout doesn't actually create the charge, it only returns a [card token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object). The `amount` value passed in the `handler.open()` call is only used for display purposes.

Once the form is submitted, in your server-side code, you'd need to retrieve the value of the `amount` form field and convert it to cents before making the [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

Additionally, you should validate the amount both on the client side and server side, to make sure it's an actual number, superior to the [minimum charge amount](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-is-the-minimum-amount-i-can-charge-with-stripe) and inferior to a reasonable maximum.